# Create a unique long in a service fabric stateful service

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a stateful service fabric service, that needs to call a third party API. When it calls the API it is obliged to provide a unique ID of type long. Is there any way in a stateful service to get the next available Long, without other instances of the service also creating the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the hashcode of the service instance if re-use is allowed and the 3rd party resource is not used concurrently by the same caller.
- You can use the [RandomNumberGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab261x43(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate 8 random bytes, and convert them into a long using [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a fairly good random long value.
  There's no guarantee that two random numbers are never the same.
  Chances are pretty good when using 8 bytes though.
- You can create an Actor or Service that keeps track of long-values currently in use (or ever used - if needed). Have it distribute fresh long values on demand.

Comment: I think the last one is probably what I was leaning to, just didn't know if there was a built in way. Also with he last one I was concerned that two instances of the service would try and create the same long. But I guess if I persist the value in an IReliableDictionary with the long as the key I can make sure that doesn't happen.